# Fixing Firefox Quantum HiDPI scaling across multiple displays

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, multiple-monitors, high-dpi

I have a laptop with a 3840x2160 screen and a second monitor with a 1680x1050 resolution. The standard Firefox DPI is far too small on the builtin screen, but when I scale the `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` value in `about:config`, the second monitor's Firefox UI gets cartoonish-ly large. Is there a way I can get Firefox to look consistent across both monitors? I am running Firefox version 63.0.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 with KDE Plasma. In my experimentation with the settings, it appears that 2.5 works well for my HiDPI screen and 1.0 works well for the external monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I now have a very similar setup:

- **Primary Screen**: Built-In Laptop Display [ **3840 x 2160** ]
- **Secondary Screen**: HDMI-connected Monitor [ **1920 x 1080** ]

---

I found a solution not only, but also to this problem **using `xrandr`** [(man page)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xrandr), **which utilizes its *scale* feature**.

**Be sure to** change the *HDMI-0* port value as per your setup.

---

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# CHANGE THIS VALUE TO MATCH YOUR SETUP
readonly display_output_port_id=HDMI-0

is_port_connected ()
{
    xrandr --listactivemonitors | grep -F "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1
}

scale_output_to_hidpi ()
{
    xrandr --output "$1" --scale 2x2 > /dev/null 2>&1
}

if is_port_connected "$display_output_port_id"
then
    if scale_output_to_hidpi "$display_output_port_id"
    then
        echo "Operation completed successfully."
    else
        echo "Operation did not succeed."
    fi
else
    echo "Port $display_output_port_id is disconnected."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Launching Firefox with environment variable `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` is the solution for me.

Current setup:

- Firefox 118
- GNOME 45
- Wayland

Things I've tried that **didn't work**:

- Customizing `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`: it's a fixed setting that will fix looking in one of the monitors.
- Installing [ffreszoom](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ffreszoom/) addon: it didn't notice the resolution and didn't change the zoom.

Thing I haven't tested:

- [Customizing `userChrome.css`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HiDPI#Firefox)
- [NoSquint Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nosquint-plus/) addon

References:

- Legacy [AutoHiDPI](https://github.com/ertug/autohidpi) addon
- [Mozilla bug 1228570: Firefox doesn't respect the DPI values in a multi-monitor setting](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1228570)
- [Mozilla bug 890156: Support per-monitor DPI on Windows 8.1 & 10 desktop](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=890156)
- [Mozilla bug 1767142: [wayland] Implement fractional-scale-v1 protocol support for fractional scaling](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1767142)
- [HiDPI on Linux - Firefox](https://nick.groenen.me/notes/hidpi-on-linux/#firefox)